# Error: Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object

Tags: matlab

when I run the code below, I got the following error :

```
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
```

`folder` can take 1 or several folders

```
for x=1:numel(folder)
    y{x} = fullfile(folder{x},'Status.xml');
    getFile = fileread(char(y{x}));
    content{x} = strtok(getFile ,';');
end


>>whos folder
  Name        Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  folder      1x1               941  struct         


>> numel(folder)
ans= 
1
```

Comment: Maybe initialise `y` before the loop as `y={}`?

Comment: it seems like `folder` is not defined when you run your code

Comment: type `>> which folder` and `>> class(folder)` and see what the output you get.

Comment: @Shai: I believe folder is defined. Or else, the error message would be for `numel(folder)` and not `folder{x}`. Or am I wrong? (It might of course be defined as something else than a cell array.)

Comment: What do you get if you simply type `folder`? What are the entries in folder? `folder.a`, `folder.b`? If you have several folders, would that be: `folder(1).a`, `folder(2).a` etc?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `folder` is a cell array, I believe this should work:

```
y = cell(numel(folder), 1);

for x=1:numel(folder)
    y{x} = fullfile(folder{x},'Status');
    getFile = fileread(char(y{x}));
    content{x} = strtok(getFile ,';');
end
```

Your error is most likely with `y{ii}`. I guess `y` is not pre-defined.

Also: you use `ii` as index in `y`, whereas you use `x` in the loop.

In case `folder` is a normal matrix, have you tried using just `folder(x)`?

## **UPDATE:**

I see from your updated question that `folder` is a [struct](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/struct.html), not a cell. Try the following, where you substitute `.field` with whatever you name your entries in `folder`.

```
y = cell(numel(folder), 1);
content = cell(numel(folder), 1);

for x=1:numel(folder)
    y{x} = fullfile(folder(x).field,'Status');
    getFile = fileread(char(y{x}));
    content{x} = strtok(getFile ,';');
end
```

Comment: I got same error when I execute y{x} = fullfile(folder{x},'Status');

Comment: getFile = fileread(char(y{x})); isn't OK as  y{x} = fullfile(folder(x).field,'Status.xml'); gives C\Status.xml whereas the expected file is Controller\Status.xml

Comment: I've updated as follow :  y{x} = fullfile(folder.field(x),'Status.xml')